# Optimization of DefineProperty in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to optimized my code when using DefineProperty. Below is a link to a jsfiddle example of what I need to do in my app.

https://jsfiddle.net/ismohamed/moqbpoku/

```
var app = angular.module("TestApp", []);

console.log(app);

app.service("MyCalc", function() {
  this.addCalcs = function(totals) {
    var newTotals = [];

    angular.forEach(totals, function(t, index) {
      newTotals[index] = {};
      Object.defineProperty(newTotals[index], 'Sum', {
        get: function() {
          console.log("Called!")
          var a = parseInt(t.a);
          var b = parseInt(t.b);
          return a + b;
        }
      });
      Object.defineProperty(newTotals[index], 'Sub', {
        get: function() {
          var a = parseInt(t.a);
          var b = parseInt(t.b);
          return a - b;
        }
      });
    });
    return newTotals;
  }
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, MyCalc) {
  $scope.myObject = [];
  $scope.savedObject = [];

  var nums1 = {};
  nums1.a = 3;
  nums1.b = 2;
  $scope.myObject[0] = nums1;

  var nums2 = {};
  nums2.a = 5;
  nums2.b = 4
  $scope.myObject[1] = nums2;

  $scope.Calcs = MyCalc.addCalcs($scope.myObject);


  // Copy the original Object - Copy Messes things up so use slice instead 
  // to get shallow coppy
  //angular.copy($scope.savedObject, $scope.myObject);
  $scope.savedObject = $scope.myObject.slice();

  var nums3 = {};
  nums3.a = 10;
  nums3.b = 5;
  $scope.savedObject[0] = nums3;

  $scope.SavedCalcs = MyCalc.addCalcs($scope.savedObject);

});
```

Basically I need to calculate in real-time the output when a user is typing in some numbers in the input textboxes. The user has groups of text boxes so each group can have it own real-time outputs, hence the use of forEach in the Calculation service which I have made. This functionality needs to remain as is.

In the example I needed to test what happened when I copied an object array as the user can make some changes and then Cancel his/her changes. By using Angular.Copy it messes things up. Therefore I found out that using slice for a shallow copy is better. Anyone knows the reason for that?

My second and real question is that as you can see I have a "Called" log output in one of the "Get" functions. Every time I change a value in one of the textboxes the Get gets called 4 times in my example. How can I optimize this so that Get is called less? Is it even possible?

Any optimization examples for this code would be greatly appreciated.